# How do you use the formula for YTM when the compounding is semi-annual?

Tags: bonds, calculation

[How do I calculate yield-to-maturity (YTM) with a simple handheld calculator?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9227/how-do-i-calculate-yield-to-maturity-ytm-with-a-simple-handheld-calculator)

do we multiply n by 2?

Comment: That would work, but you also need to divide the interest rate by 2.  That is, each year, the value increases by the factor (1+I/2)(1+I/2) instead of by the factor (1+I). Note that (1+I/2)(1+I/2) = 1 + I + (I/2)^2 and so you could also just change I to I+(I/2)^2 and keep the number of periods the same

Comment: And having no power to change your great comment to an answer, I'll just suggest it here. It's 90% of the way there, just add tiny bit more. Your decision.